# WooCommerce - How to remove DIV shadow and change background color

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I have a website with a product page that need changes: 
http://weardenali.com/product/everyday-messenger

I'm trying to

a) Change the background color

b) Remove the shadow box

It works on the iPad (which is 768px in height) but as soon as the website height decreases below 768px, the swipe function stops working.

I hope somebody can assist me with this .

This image of my site is  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdpHv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions in order:

a) The background of your page is specified as an element style. Probably from the WordPress styling or any other cause that I cannot immediately determine. The root element is styled by .product-main in the sf-combined.min CSS file. Here you can set the background-color to anything you want, as proposed:

```
.product-main {
background-color: #anything;
}
```

Considering this may or may not work, I suggest you try to determine why the .product-main has a element style of #fcfcfc. The following is *not recommended* but you can always set .product-main { background-color: #anything !important; } to override any settings. But this is *not* best practise.

b) in your CSS in sf-combined.min.css on line 15 (which may be inaccurate because it's a minified CSS document) you have the following line:

.product-fw-split div.product div.summary.

Remove the box shadow entries from the CSS:

```
.product-fw-split div.product div.summary {
padding: 40px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

And the box shadow should disappear. Please do check for any responsive queries that may affect the same thing on mobile devices (which I didn't check).

c) I could not determine entirely what your question was in c. I believe you want to know how to prevent the swipe functionality from stopping working when resizing on devices smaller than 768px? It might be WooThumbs intended functionality, in which case I suggest you head over to CodeCanyons support and try to get an answer directly from them. https://codecanyon.net/item/woothumbs-awesome-product-imagery/2867927

Hope it helps.
Next time it might be easier to split your questions off into multiple questions, so that others can find answers more easily.

Comment: Thank you for your help. All your suggestions worked, and for c) i would consult with Woothumbs

Comment: Glad it helped! If you find your answer from WooThumbs, you might want to edit your original question to add the answer you found, for future reference!

Answer (score 0):

Here are your changes:
A) change `product-main clearfix` style `background-color: #fcfcfc;` to your wish color.

B) Remove

```
Remove /* -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1); */
Remove /* box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);`
```

from your 
`summary`
 class or rename your div.

C) i just test it in chrome version 55........ simulated iphone 5 and ypur carousel still working.

[image: testImage]